# Error while creating NIC in Azure Powershell, just because of invalid Private IP address,

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

This was what I wrote:

```
$server1nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgname1 -Name "L-firstyear-ec-nic-02" -Location $location -Subnet $vnet1.subnets[0] -PublicIpAddress $server1pip -PrivateIpAddress "192.168.0.0/16"
```

Here, `$rgname1` is resource group name; `$location` is chosen as eastasia; `$vnet1` is a virtual network which has 4 subnets; `$server1pip` is public IP address.

And the error it showed:

> New-AzNetworkInterface: Private static IP address value 192.168.0.0/16 is invalid.
> StatusCode: 400
> ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
> ErrorCode: InvalidPrivateIPAddressFormat
> ErrorMessage: Private static IP address value 192.168.0.0/16 is invalid.
> OperationID : 2f4a9969-53a1-4ec2-984f-ffe165877c93

Comment: Any more updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The value for the parameter `-PrivateIpAddress` should be like `192.168.0.x` in the command you use. It must be a certain IP address in the subnet that you use. For example:

```
$server1nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $rgname1 -Name "L-firstyear-ec-nic-02" -Location $location -Subnet $vnet1.subnets[0] -PublicIpAddress $server1pip -PrivateIpAddress "192.168.0.10"
```